# What command counts the number of an specific type of file (eg: csv) in a directory on OS X?

Tags: command-line, mac, filesystems

What is the command line to count the number of an specific type of file (eg: csv) of a directory on OS X (only files, excluding directories and subdirectories)?

The below command works for any kind, but it's considering other types.

```
find [directory] -print | wc -l
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command will count the number of `.csv` files in the current directory and all subdirectories.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.csv' | wc -l
```

Explanation:

Find in the current directory `.` (and all subdirectories), a file `-type f`, matching a case-insensitive pattern `-iname *.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved:

```
 find [your directory] -type f -name "*.csv" -print | wc -l
```

Comment: You don't need `-print` and consider using `-iname` for case-insensitive matching.  See my answer for more details.